# Homebrew NNet Troubles

Tags: neural-network, numpy

I have been trying to develop my own homebrew scalable neural network. I was hoping someone could Identify what aspect of my training process is most likely failing. I believe it may be due to either the learning rate causing odd overshooting, the way I am streaming the data into the network, or incorrect implementation of RMSprop.

I have been trying to test the robustness of my program using the double spiral test, and when this gave me problems I tried to have the network learn a simple hyperbolic shape which also somehow failed. I am using RMSprop for all my optimization and for the spiral problem I was using -LogLikelihood as a cost.

I have been experiencing the same problem of a fluctuating loss function (the training loss), with the only commonality across all my loss graphs is a decrease followed by a increase in the early epochs

I have only solved even simpler problems than these using this network which was without using RMSprop

[image: The following is an image of the loss in the learning of a hyperbolic function over 8000 epochs. I am using a Standard Error (target-output)^2.]

I am using 2 to 4 layers of ReLu and TanH activations with ~15 neurons each and all give me similar graphs regardless of the data it is trying to match and regardless of the order of the network. While performing the spiral test I would always end up with dead ReLu neurons regardless of my initial LR(alpha).

If you are wondering how I partitioned my saved values I stored:
-Output of each layer
-Error with respect to the output of each layer
-weights and biases
-learning rate per each weight
-velocity of the learning rate per each weight

The following is my code for my RMSprop implementation:

```
    def Optimizer(self, type, weightError, InitalLR, Rho, Epsilon, Beta, layer):
    if type == "RMSProp":
        ### the weight error is a matrix equivilent in size to the weight matrix
        ### the velocity and LR are also in this same shape and update per each weight
        self.Velocity[layer] = Beta*self.Velocity[layer] + (1-Beta)*np.power(weightError, 2)
        self.LR[layer] += InitalLR/(Epsilon + np.sqrt(self.Velocity[layer]))
```

The following is my code for my weightUpdates:

```
 def UpdateWeights(self, type, InitalLR, Rho, Epsilon, Beta):
    for i in range(len(self.weightTensor)):
        # the following calculates dCost/dLayerOutput * dLayerOutput/dLinearSummation
        Output_and_Activation_Error = np.multiply(self.outputErrors[i+1], self.ActivationFunctions(deriv=True, type=self.LayerID[i+1][2], input=(self.outputMatrix[i+1])))
        # Now calculates dCost/dLayerOutput * dLayerOutput/dLinearSummation * (dLinearSummation/dweight) = dCost/dweight
        WeightERROR = (np.reshape(self.outputMatrix[i], (len(self.outputMatrix[i]), 1)) @ np.reshape(Output_and_Activation_Error, (len(Output_and_Activation_Error), 1)).T)
        # Takes this dCost/dweight and plugs it into the optimizer which updates the learning rate saved in the class
        self.Optimizer(type, WeightERROR, InitalLR, Rho, Epsilon, Beta, i)
        # update
        self.weightTensor[i] -= np.multiply(self.LR[i], WeightERROR)
```

Some guidance on how to interpret loss graphs would be useful as well. Thank you.